# Spring Open-Feign fails to start with more than one spring.application.name used in Config-client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-feign

In my application we use spring cloud config where we host file backed properties like below

Config Server

```
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///${SRC.HOME}/config/,file:///${SRC.HOME}/config/app1/,file:///${SRC.HOME}/config/app2/,file:///${SRC.HOME}/config/app3/
```

Config Client

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:7070/,spring.application.name=app1,app2,app3
```

Lately we are introducing spring open-feign and noticed main class boots up only when there is single application name. The moment you provide names in comma separated way (spring.application.name=app1,app2,app3) it breaks with below exception

Questions

1. Any one faced it ever ?
2. What am I doing wrong probably?
3. Do I need to change the Config loading approach such that I provide
   only single name ?
4. How to accommodate this feature keeping the config loading approach
   the same.

   ```
   Spring-boot Version -2.1.5.RELEASE
   Open-Feign - 2.1.1.Release
   Spring-Cloud - Greenwich.SR1
   ```

Exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String  at
>   com.netflix.config.ConfigurationBasedDeploymentContext.getValueFromConfig(ConfigurationBasedDeploymentContext.java:329)
>   ~[archaius-core-0.7.6.jar:0.7.6]

Answer (score 0):

1. each app should only has one unique name. (consider if you are using eurake for regiter, you can have mulitply instance of the same app to load balance)
2. if you want different config file for same app, you can use profile e.g. spring.profiles.active=dev2.

btw, not sure why need you mulitply locations for config files, but I think one collective location for all config files is common practice.